# What is the charge distribution on inner walls of arbitrary cavity of a spherical metallic shell with charge present in it?

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider a spherical metallic shell with a cavity and a charge $q$ present inside. The field at outside points will be as if charge was placed at the center of the shell.That means the field due to the charge $q$ and that due to charge on inner walls cancel for all points outside the cavity. With this information I was trying to calculate the charge distribution on inner walls of an arbitrary cavity. But I was unsuccessful in my attempts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try the Gauss theorem? The field inside the metal is zero.

Comment: Try using method of images. For example in Jackson's textbook on electrodynamics (chapter 2) you have explicitly solved problem when the charge is outside of the sphere (eq.(2.5) in 3rd edition).